# Optaplanner ConcurrentModificationException when modifying Solution from SolverEventListener

Tags: java, optaplanner

I'm solving a scheduling problem using OptaPlanner solver integrated into a JavaFX GUI that updates on each improvement. 
Since connecting it to the GUI, this exception frequently happens after the construction heuristic finishes.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.cloner.FieldAccessingSolutionCloner$FieldAccessingSolutionClonerRun.cloneCollection(FieldAccessingSolutionCloner.java:297)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.cloner.FieldAccessingSolutionCloner$FieldAccessingSolutionClonerRun.process(FieldAccessingSolutionCloner.java:280)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.cloner.FieldAccessingSolutionCloner$FieldAccessingSolutionClonerRun.processQueue(FieldAccessingSolutionCloner.java:273)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.cloner.FieldAccessingSolutionCloner$FieldAccessingSolutionClonerRun.cloneSolution(FieldAccessingSolutionCloner.java:206)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.cloner.FieldAccessingSolutionCloner.cloneSolution(FieldAccessingSolutionCloner.java:72)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.cloneSolution(AbstractScoreDirector.java:142)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.scope.DefaultSolverScope.setWorkingSolutionFromBestSolution(DefaultSolverScope.java:198)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.runPhases(DefaultSolver.java:217)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:176)
    at no.scheduling.shifts.solver.ShiftOptaPlanner.solve(ShiftOptaPlanner.java:124)
    at application.ScheduleSolver.run(ScheduleSolver.java:69)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My GUI code does modify the received solutions as the items it contains have to be displayed to the user in a sorted fashion. 
When I use defensive cloning for solutions provided by the listener's `bestSolutionChanged()` method, the problem disappears. 
Am I doing something wrong here or it might be possible that event listener sometimes gets a wired instance used by OptaPlanner instead of a defensive clone? 
I'd really like to avoid the cloning step, as the cloning functionality I currently have available is limited and slow.

**EDIT:** With some further debugging, I think I was able to pinpoint the issue in the OptaPlanner source (6.4.0 Final) 
After finishing the construction heuristic phase, the `updateBestSolution()` method in the `BestSolutionRecaller` puts the same solution instance in the `fireBestSolutionChanged()` as it stores in the `solverScope`:

```
 public void updateBestSolution(DefaultSolverScope solverScope, Solution solution, int uninitializedVariableCount) {
        (...)
        solverScope.setBestSolution(solution);
        (...)
        solverEventSupport.fireBestSolutionChanged(solution, uninitializedVariableCount);
    }
```

This exactly same instance then goes through cloning in the `setWorkingSolutionFromBestSolution` at the same time as my GUI thread is sorting the event list in it and exception is thrown as the list of events is iterated in `FieldAccessingSolutionClonerRun.cloneCollection()`. 
Guess the solution to the issue would be cloning the solution that goes to `fireBestSolutionChanged()`?

Did I stumble upon a subtle bug or I'm doing something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `ConcurrentModificationException` has to do with 1)modifying an Object   from a Thread and simultaneously doing something to it and from another Thread `or` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do a deep clone (= defensive copy) during bestSolutionEvent. optaplanner-core doesn't do it either because of performance reasons (there's no bug in that code, but planner does do a planning clone (!= deep clone) in BestSolutionRecaller).

Instead, do a deep clone in your `ProblemFactChange`s.

A deep clone is different from a planning clone (which is explained in the docs). The 7.0.0.Beta2 docs contain an explanation with this to clarify this further:

[image]